# MVC Redirect on user having specific claim

Tags: model-view-controller, wif, claims-based-identity

I Have Claims Based Identity, Authentication and Authorization.

In my ClaimsAuthenticationManager I transform User Federation Token Claims and add my application specific Claims to the ClaimsIdentity for the ClaimsPrincipal.Identity.

If the federated user is not registered locally in the application I generate a     `"http://xml/claims/newUser"` claim with "true" as value.

Now, in my application I need to redirect to "RegisterUser" action in "Account" controller if User has this specific claim in his claimset.

This may be simple but I just not finding a logical solution to this scenario. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I found for my problem was solved with this simple IFilterAttribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple=true)]
public class RedirectOnClaimFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{

    public string ClaimType { get; set; }
    public string ClaimValue { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }

    #region IActionFilter Members

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity id = (ClaimsIdentity)filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity;

        if (id.HasClaim(p => p.Type == ClaimType && string.Compare(p.Value, ClaimValue, true) == 0))
            filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction(Controller, Action);

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity id = (ClaimsIdentity)filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity;

        if (id.HasClaim(p => p.Type == ClaimType && string.Compare(p.Value, ClaimValue, true) == 0))
            filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction(Controller, Action);


    }


    private ActionResult RedirectToAction(string Controller, string Action)
    {
        return new RedirectToRouteResult(new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary()
                                                {
                                                    {"Controller", Controller},
                                                    { "Action", Action}
                                                });
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Then I can select a specific claim to validate on Controller calls like so:

```
[RedirectOnClaimFilter(Action="WaitForApproval",
    Controller="Account",
    ClaimType = "http://solution/claims/pendinguser",
    ClaimValue="true")]
[RedirectOnClaimFilter(Action = "RegisterFederated",
    Controller = "Account",
    ClaimType = "http://solution/claims/newuser",
    ClaimValue = "true")]
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(SecurityException), View = "Error")]
public class OrganizationController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult OrganizationAction()
    {
         return View();
    }
}
```

It will check for a specific Claim in the Principal's Claimset, if found, the User will be redirected to specific Controller and Action.

Answer (score 1):

Wif-style way to do this is using a ClaimsAuthorizationManager (thanks to @leastprivilege [article](http://leastprivilege.com/2011/04/30/what-i-like-about-wifs-claims-based-authorization/)):

```
try
{
    ClaimsPrincipalPermission.CheckAccess(“User”, “Newbie”);
}
catch (SecurityException ex)
{
    RedirectToAction("RegisterUser", "Account");
}
```

CheckAccess called ClaimsAuthorizationManager.CheckAccess() where you will implement concrete claim-checking for this set of action, resource and principal:

```
var principal = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
if (principal != null)
{
     var newUserClaim =  principal.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => string.Compare(c.Type, "http://xml/claims/newUser", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
}
```

UPDATE
Most simple way is a HasClaim() method of Principal:

```
var principal = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
If (principal.HasClaim("http://xml/claims/newUser", "true")) 
{
    RedirectToAction("RegisterUser", "Account");
}
```

Comment: In the context of the following code:

`public class AuthorizationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager
    {
       
        
        public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
        { 
    RedirectToAction("Controller","Action");
}
}`

The `RedirectToAction` method is not available.

Comment: RedirectToAction must be in controller, called after chains of ClaimsPrincipalPermission.CheckAccess->AuthrizationManager.CheckAccess() return security exception.

Comment: I add another solution with HasClaim()

Answer (score 0):

You may use **Thinktecture.IdentityModel** which has Attribute named **ClaimsAuthorize** that will automatically redirect the User to Login Page. In order to use Thinktecture.IdentityModel you need to add the package to your MVC application using Nuget

```
Install-Package Thinktecture.IdentityModel
```

If you are already using ClaimsPrincipalPermission then, you already have ClaimsAuthorizationManager class for checking / aurhorizing claims in your application, in that case, you wont have to do anything else. Now you can decorate your MVC Action Methods as follows:

```
[ClaimsAuthorize("View", "About")]
public ActionResult About(int id=0)
{

    return View();
}
```

If the current logged in user does not have claims for 'View' action on 'About' resource, he/she will be redirected to the Login Page.